# Couldn't Create the Expected Query

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I am new in Sql Could you please help it with this problem.

```
id |name |reportingTo
----------------------
1   A       NULL
2   B       1
3   C       1
4   D       2
5   E       2
6   F       5
```

I want the expected output as below. How i can impliment this with one query.

```
Output
------------------------
Name    Reporter

A           No One
B           A
C           A
D           B
E           B
F           E
```

I have tried this but not working

```
    select name,(case  when  reporting = null then 'MD' 
        ELSE  (select a.name from testLevel a inner join  testLevel b on a.id=b.reporting where a.id=b.reporting)
        END) reportingto
        From testLevel
```

Thanks In-advance..

Comment: Take a peak at the COALESCE() function. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a self join? So something like

```
SELECT r.Name ,
    rTo.Name Reporter
FROM testLevel r LEFT JOIN
     testLevel rTo ON r.ReportingTo = rTo.id
```

Based on the fact that you have picked 3 RDBMSs you might want to take a look at

MySQL [IFNULL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull):

```
IFNULL(rTo.Name, 'No One') Reporter
```

SQL Server [ISNULL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx)

```
ISNULL(rTo.Name, 'No One') Reporter
```

Comment: I will try it but the first sample query is not working Error:- The multi-part identifier "tTo.id" could not be bound.

Comment: Sorry, changed from `tTo` to `rTo`

Answer (score 1):

Keep joins and subselects out of your select statement.

MySQL and Oracle are two seperate databases...choose on or the other

```
select a.name, b.name
from reportingto a left join reportingto b on a.id = b.reportingto
```

that will give names..use a isnull statement to resolve the 'no one' when bnot found.   Note the left join makes this possible, an inner join won't work here.

```
select a.name, isnull(b.name, 'No One')
from reportingto a left join reportingto b on a.id = b.reportingto
```

Comment: That should be working...you've tagged your question with 3 seperate databases, each with slightly varying syntax.  Pick one...which database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server:

You can also achieve this by using a Common Table Expression:

```
WITH CTE (
    SELECT DISTINCT reportingTo, name
    FROM testLevel
)

SELECT DISTINCT A.name AS Name, ISNULL(B.name, 'No One') AS Reporter
FROM testLevel A
LEFT JOIN CTE B ON A.id = B.reportingTo
```

Or using a subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.name AS Name, ISNULL(B.name, 'No One') AS Reporter
FROM testLevel A
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT reportingTo, name
    FROM testLevel
) B ON A.id = B.reportingTo
```